# Track telegram messenger client

Tags: android, api, tracking, messenger, telegram

For administrative purposes, I think it might be dangerous if you build a messenger with absolutely no administration whatsoever.

Unfortunately the Telegram API does not allow you to view any chat logs so if someone breaks any applicable law then I would not be able to lead an investigation.

So is there a way to be able to track messages sent through the API by integrating maybe another API in the client code so I can view chat logs and other information for administrative purposes.

Would GCM work? Any project that you know can do this?

Answer (score 0):

GCM will work, because you will store your messages in your server, you have control on your server. You can view this helpful [tutorial](http://javapapers.com/android/android-chat-with-google-gcm-xmpp/).

You can try to use [Parse](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide) to store the messages, so you can view the messages in your Parse's application dashboard. Also, Parse is compatible on both Android and iOS, so you can build application in both platforms. You can visit [Parse Android Chat tutorial](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Building-Simple-Chat-Client-with-Parse) from CodePath.